# efficient way to merge consecutive list elements based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

given a list of tuples where the values are sorted, what is the most efficient way of merging consecutive elements if the difference between the elements is less than a value `x`

in the following list, if `x=100` then `(287, 790)` and `(855, 945)` would be merged into `(287,945)`, then `(287,945)` would merge with `(955, 2205)` into `(287,2205)` and so on

```
[(287, 790),
 (855, 945),
 (955, 2205),
 (2230, 2264),
 (2362, 2729),
 (3906, 4473)]
```

and this would be the output in this case:

```
[(287, 2729),
 (3906, 4473)]
```

Comment: Considering the 1st merge, how does `x = 100` fit there? Also how would one calculate the distance between 2 tuples?

Comment: @CristiFati considering the first merge, 855 - 790 <= 100 is True. I added a broken piece of code to demonstrate what am expecting. Hope this clarifies what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
orig_list = [
 (287, 790),
 (855, 945),
 (955, 2205),
 (2230, 2264),
 (2362, 2729),
 (3906, 4473)]
merged_list = []
# iterate through original list
orig_iter = iter(orig_list)
# pop the first element and keep track of it as the "last tuple visited"
last_tuple = next(orig_iter)
for next_tuple in orig_iter:
    # if tuples are too close, merge them
    if (next_tuple[0] - last_tuple[1]) < 100:
        last_tuple = (last_tuple[0], next_tuple[1])
    # otherwise, push the last_tuple to the new list and replace it
    else:
        merged_list.append(last_tuple)
        last_tuple = next_tuple
# when we're done traversing the list, push whatever's remaining onto the end
merged_list.append(last_tuple)

print(merged_list)
# [(287, 2729), (3906, 4473)]
```

Note that `(287, 2205)` merges with `(2230, 2264)` since the difference is less than 100. I suspect this was a typo in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're only merging this once (meaning you don't try to produce several different resulting tuples from one original tuple), the best you can do is going to be an `O(n)` solution, or basically a for loop.

```py
x = 100
to_merge = [(287, 790),
 (855, 945),
 (955, 2205),
 (2230, 2264),
 (2362, 2729),
 (3906, 4473)]

def merge(lst, x):
    if not lst or len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst
    new_lst = []
    start, end = lst[0]
    for start1, end1 in lst[1:]:
        if start1 - end < x:
            end = end1
        else:
            new_lst.append((start, end))
            start, end = start1, end1
    new_lst.append((start, end))
    return new_lst

print(merge(to_merge, x))
```

If you were to do this multiple times to the same original list, then you might find using a dynamic programming method more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is like [M Z's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63231691/4518341), but using a nested list instead of a list of tuples, to make the merging easier:

```
def merge(intervals, difference):
    merged = []
    prev_end = float('-inf')  # Initial loop value
    for start, end in intervals:
        if start-prev_end < difference:
            # Merge, i.e. set the new top end value
            merged[-1][1] = end
        else:
            # The current interval becomes the top
            merged.append([start, end])
        prev_end = end  # For next loop
    return merged


some_list = [
    (287, 790),
    (855, 945),
    (955, 2205),
    (2230, 2264),
    (2362, 2729),
    (3906, 4473)]
print(merge(some_list, 100))  # -> [[287, 2729], [3906, 4473]]
```

Converting the result to a list of tuples is also O(n).

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = 100
data = [
        (287, 790),
        (855, 945),
        (955, 2205),
        (2230, 2264),
        (2362, 2729),
        (3906, 4473)
]

def merger(x, data):
    merged = [data[0],]
    the_others = [data[i] for i in range(1, len(data)) if (data[i][0]-data[i-1][1])>x]
    merged.extend(the_others)
    return merged

print(merger(x, data))
```